# Conformal + Distortion Coordinate Transform

Tags: java, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, geotools

I am trying to convert geometry coordinate reference system of some land parcels in Australia into another using java geotools api and opengis libraries. i.e WSG84 (EPSG:4326) to GDA2020 / MGA zone 50 (EPSG:7850), or WSG84 (EPSG:4326) to GDA2020 / PCG2020 (EPSG:8031). By now the converted coordinates have some deviation from the original coordinates it suppose to be. Now my requirement is to perform Conformal + Distortion transformation explained in this article which is more accurate - https://www.icsm.gov.au/datum/gda-transformation-products-and-tools/transformation-grids

However I am not very sure on what changes I need for the current code to do above. I did some google for find some code examples but couldn't find what I wanted. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Query       query       = new Query();
DataStore   dataStore   = getDataStore();
FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(featureTypeName);

query.setFilter(ECQL.toFilter("land_id='" + landID + "'"));

FeatureCollection           collection      = source.getFeatures(query);
FeatureIterator             iterator        = collection.features();
CoordinateReferenceSystem   sourceCRS       = collection.getSchema().getCoordinateReferenceSystem(); // WSG 84
List<Geometry>              geometryList    = new ArrayList<Geometry>();
CoordinateReferenceSystem   targetCRS       = getCRS(targetEPSGCode); // GDA2020 / MGA zone 50

while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    Feature             feature =   (Feature) iterator.next();
    GeometryAttribute   geom    =   feature.getDefaultGeometryProperty();
    Object              geomVal =   geom.getValue();

    if (geomVal instanceof Geometry)
    {
        MathTransform   mathTransform       = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS);
        Geometry        transformedGeometry = JTS.transform((Geometry) geomVal, mathTransform);

        geometryList.add(transformedGeometry);
    }
}

// Use geometryList for further stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the required [NTv2 grid file](https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids/blob/master/GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb) and save it to your projects `src/main/resources/org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift` folder and recompile the project. There is more discussion and some example code to help you check it is being picked up in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313523/79) over on https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I have placed https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids/blob/master/GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb in above location of my maven multi-module project (within sub project), however it does not work for me. I have checked the logs and seems file has never been considered while transform. Do you have any idea why